# how to use on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `on` event. Code

```
$(".draggable").on("mouseover", function () {
                if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                    $(this).data("init", true).draggable();
                }
});
```

but the above code is not working. The draggable plugin is not apply on elements. Now if i replace the `on` event with `live` then it starts working. Code

```
$(".draggable").live("mouseover", function () {
                if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                    $(this).data("init", true).draggable();
                }
});
```

can anybody explain me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `.live()` works, then that likely means that the element you're manipulating is not present when the code runs.

This either means you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready before running the code, or you need to use the delegated version of `.on` instead.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("mouseover", ".draggable", function () {
                    if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                        $(this).data("init", true).draggable();
                    }
    });
});
```

You should replace `document` with a selector for the deepest nested container that contains all the `.draggable` elements.

Answer (score 2):

it depend on which jquery version you use

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

refer this [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more details